# Scala code using static method in interface gives error Static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have a code which uses a java library cron-utils which uses static methods in interface (though I have set target and source to 1.8 in pom below)
and during compiling throws this error

`Static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8` for the part where a static method from interface is used `ExecutionTime.forCron(cron)`

This is the code in the library where static method is defined in interface

```
public interface ExecutionTime {

    /**
     * Creates execution time for given Cron.
     *
     * @param cron - Cron instance
     * @return ExecutionTime instance
     */
    public static ExecutionTime forCron(final Cron cron)
```

I have used it like this in my code

```
def getInterval(schedule: String): Long = {
  val parser = new CronParser(CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.UNIX))
  val cron = parser.parse(schedule)
  val currDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.now().toString)
  val next = ExecutionTime.forCron(cron).nextExecution(currDateTime).get().toInstant
  val prev = ExecutionTime.forCron(cron).lastExecution(currDateTime).get().toInstant
  Duration.between(prev, next).toMillis
}
```

I have set Java 1.8 as source and target in pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
            <args>conf:cat=other-match-analysis:error</args>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have my scala plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Still it throws the same error saying `static methods in interface require -target:jvm-1.8`

I tried using older versions of the library which gives me many more unavoidable errors.

Any help figuring how I can set the target to java 1.8, is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Java class instead and used the CronUtils library then  used the Java class in scala

```
import com.cronutils.model.Cron;
import com.cronutils.model.CronType;
import com.cronutils.model.definition.CronDefinitionBuilder;
import com.cronutils.model.time.ExecutionTime;
import com.cronutils.parser.CronParser;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class CronUtil  {
    public Long getInterval(String schedule ) {
        CronParser parser = new CronParser(CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.UNIX));
        Cron cron = parser.parse(schedule);
        ZonedDateTime currDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.now().toString());
        Instant next = ExecutionTime.forCron(cron).nextExecution(currDateTime).get().toInstant();
        Instant prev = ExecutionTime.forCron(cron).lastExecution(currDateTime).get().toInstant();
        return Duration.between(prev, next).toMillis();
    }
}
```

Finally used it in in scala without any errors

```
val interval = new CronUtil().getInterval(schedule)
```